# Value of SCOPE_IDENTITY on bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `MyTable` and I have an `After trigger(On Insert)` on that table.

When I do run bulk insert statement on `MyTable`, it fires the trigger to captured the data inserted (i.e for audit log purpose).

We have truncated table `MyTable` and now inserting below 5 records in the table. Also, the `Auditlog` table has existing data. Let's say 500 records already in the audit log table.

My question is, what will `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` return in the case of `BULK INSERT` statement on a table when table has a trigger on it?

```
--Create table 
Create table MyTable 
(
    FirstCol int identity(1,1) primary key,
    SecondCol varchar(10)
)

Create table AuditLog
(
    AID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Comments varchar(50)
)

--Insert data to MyTable
INSERT INTO MyTable (SecondCol)
VALUES ('First'), ('Second'), ('Third'), ('Fourth'), ('Fifth')

Select * from MyTable
Select Scope_identity()
```

Comment: What did that last query return?

Comment: I have not created trigger till now but I was wondering what will scope_identity return in the above case. I know scope_identity returns the last value but in case of bulk insert does the behaviour changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scope_identity` returns the last created id in the same scope. The trigger runs in a separate scope, so the function will return the same thing as if the trigger didn't exist.

Comment: Do you mean that scope_identity in my case will return 5 or will it return 505?

Comment: @PareshJ: You will get the id from the last record inserted in the same scope, so that would be 5 from the last record inserted in `MyTable`.

Comment: Please answer two queries. (1) So you mean if I write Select Scope_identity in trigger it will return me 505 instead of 5. (2) If i use @@Identity in trigger, it will still return 5. Am I right??

Comment: @PareshJ: 1) Yes, in the trigger the `scope_identity` function will return the id created in that scope, i.e. the `AuditLog` table. 2) If you use `@@identity` it will return the last id create in any scope for the current session (connection), so in the trigger it will return 5 (from `MyTable`) before you insert the last record in `AuditLog`, and 505 after.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --Temp Table to Get Result     
    DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)
    --Insert data to MyTable
    INSERT INTO MyTable (SecondCol)
    --Get Result in "INSERTED" Table 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.FirstCol INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
    VALUES ('First'), ('Second'), ('Third'), ('Fourth'), ('Fifth')
    select * from @OutputTbl
    select * from MyTable
```